# mysql of searching where without any data by foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem of searching data .

A table

```
A_id name  
1    apple 
2    orange
3     sexy
```

B table

```
B_id A_id comment 
1      1         abcde
```

how can i get the a_id were without any comment in b table

i want the sql return

```
a_id name 
2 orange 
3 sexy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLs `NOT EXISTS` operator is for that purpose:

```
select a_id, name
from A as AT
where not exists 
     (select *
      from B as BT
      where BT.a_id=AT.a_id)
```

Comment: please upvote and/or accept as answer, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing is by using left join and null check

```
select a.a_id, a.name
from a
LEFT JOIN b
ON b.a_id=a.a_id
WHERE b.a_id is Null
```